# "Необходимо уточнить" — новое название причины закрытия, а также исправленное пояснение к ней

Tags: предложение, причины-закрытия, перевод-содержимого

Итак, что мы имеем сейчас. Причина для закрытия:

> **Необходимо конкретизировать**
>
> Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную
>   проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного
>   ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший
>   вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации.

Конкретизировать. 16 букв! Ух. Предлагаю более русский, более "точный" и более короткий перевод — уточнить. 8 букв против 16-и. Получаем: **Необходимо уточнить**

Идём дальше.

> Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную
>   проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного
>   ответа.

Признаюсь честно, мне пришлось несколько раз перечитать:

> описывал конкретную
>   проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного
>   ответа.

чтобы понять причём тут "достаточная детализация" и "определение" ответа. Поэтому также предлагаю подправить "перевод", примерно в таком ключе:

> Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос таким образом, чтобы в нём описывалась
>   определённая задача с достаточным пояснением к ней. Это позволит дать
>   более точный ответ на него. Не задавайте несколько вопросов сразу. Для
>   уточнения см. "Как задать хороший вопрос?"

---

Ну и всё вместе.

> **Необходимо уточнить**
>
> Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос таким образом, чтобы в нём описывалась
>   определённая задача с достаточным пояснением к ней. Это позволит дать
>   более точный ответ на него. Не задавайте несколько вопросов сразу. Для
>   уточнения см. "Как задать хороший вопрос?"

Answer (score 5):

Немного истории. До ~декабря 2019 у нас были причины закрытия:

- Too broad -> Слишком общий
- Unclear what are you asking -> Непонятна суть вопроса

Затем английские формулировки поменялись. Я предложил следующие переводы:

- Needs more focus -> Необходимо конкретизировать
- Needs details or clarity -> Необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями

Т.е. то, что вы предлагаете, по замыслу предназначалось другой причине... Но модераторы утвердили для нее другой вариант (старый), поэтому сейчас мы имеем

- Needs more focus -> Необходимо конкретизировать
- Needs details or clarity -> Непонятна суть вопроса

Думаю, если что-то менять, надо сделать это согласованно, чтобы либо обе начинались с "необходимо", либо обе использовали старый принцип. Я согласен, что "Необходимо конкретизировать" тут сомнительный вариант, так как это не дословный перевод, но и "Необходимо уточнить" тут не очень подходит. Это не про точность, а про объем. Скорее уж "Необходимо сузить" тогда.

Comment: Да, я вы вообще две в одну объединил.